# uniform random variables and their expectations

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

Let X and Y be independent uniform random variables on (0,1).  Let $Z=\lfloor{\frac{1}{X+Y}}\rfloor$

I want to find $P(Z=0)$ and $E[Z]$

Firstly, I got that:

$$f_{X+Y}(a)=\begin{cases}
a&0\leq a\leq 1\\2-a&1<a<2\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Thus for $Z=0$, $X+Y>1$ so $P(Z=0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

But I have no idea how to find $E[Z]$.

Comment: Hi :) Let $A:=X+Y$, then $Z=\lfloor \frac 1A\rfloor$ and $\displaystyle E(Z) =\int_0^2 \lfloor \frac 1a\rfloor\cdot f(a) \,da=\int_0^1\lfloor \frac 1a\rfloor\cdot a\,da=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{1/(k+1) }^{1/k}\lfloor \frac 1a\rfloor\cdot a\,da$

Comment: An addendum to @Jochen's comment: check the result is $\pi^2/12$